# ArrayLists are getting edited without being accessed

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a shuffle class to shuffle an ArrayList of Strings (word order and letters of the words), however, it seems that the method shuffle() accesses the shuffleWords() method, it sets realWords AND compToWords equal to the shuffled realWords, when really only compToWords should be.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class Shuffle{

private static ArrayList<String> realWords = new ArrayList<String>();
private static ArrayList<String> shuffWords  = new ArrayList<String>();
private static ArrayList<String> compToWords = new ArrayList<String>();

private static ArrayList<String> shuffleWords(ArrayList<String> word){
    for (int k = word.size()-1; k>= 0; k--){
        int r = (int)(Math.floor(Math.random() * k));
        String temp = word.get(r);
        word.set(r,word.get(k));
        word.set(k,temp);
    }
    return word;
}
private static String shuffleLetters(String word){
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(word);
    for (int k = word.length()-1; k>= 0; k--){
        int r = (int)(Math.floor(Math.random() * k));
        char temp = str.charAt(r);
        str.setCharAt(r, str.charAt(k));
        str.setCharAt(k,temp);
    }
    return str.toString().toLowerCase();
}
public static void shuffle(){
    compToWords = shuffleWords(realWords);
    for(int i = 0; i <compToWords.size();i++)shuffWords.add(shuffleLetters(compToWords.get(i)));
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in `shuffleWords(realWords)` but no where did you make a copy of realWords, so you are manipulating the original list.

**Solution:**

Inside shuffleWords make a copy of the input list:

```
private static List<String> shuffleWords(List<String> input) {
    List<String> word = new ArrayList<>(input);
    /* ... */
}
```

See also the "Passing Reference Data Type Arguments" section in this Java Tutorial: [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html).

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize that could happen

Answer (score 1):

In the first line of shuffle(), you use

```
compToWords = shuffleWords(realWords);
```

This makes the list compToWords refer to the list returned by shuffleWords. The list returned by shuffleWords in this case is realWords.

```
private static ArrayList<String> shuffleWords(ArrayList<String> word){
for (int k = word.size()-1; k>= 0; k--){
    int r = (int)(Math.floor(Math.random() * k));
    String temp = word.get(r);
    word.set(r,word.get(k));
    word.set(k,temp);
}
return word;
}
```

In this code here the arraylist word still refers to realWords. The changes you make to word, in this case, also apply to realWords.

Instead the easiest solution would be to make a copy of your list in shuffleWords, otherwise the array list you create will only serve as a reference to the original array list.